# Context and Variable Declaration

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, constructive-mathematics

I am a beginner in type theories. I have a basic question about the notion of *context*. It is commonly found in a textbook on type theories that a *context* (sometimes also called an *environment*) is defined as a sequence of *variable declarations* (or *assumptions*) such as $\langle x_1:C_1,x_2:C_2,...,x_n:C_n\rangle$. But I find in my handouts that the following sequence is also a valid context:

$\Gamma=\langle\mathbb{N}:Type, 1:\mathbb{N}, suc:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}, suc(suc 1):\mathbb{N}\rangle$

My question is: none of the expressions in $\Gamma$ contains any free variable, so how should I understand the definition of context as a sequence of *variable declarations*?

---

Here is the text that I am referring to in my handout:

> An empty context $\langle\ \rangle$ can be extended by a new type $\mathbb{N}$. We get the following judgment:
> $$\langle\mathbb{N}:Type\rangle\vdash\mathbb{N}:Type.$$
> This judgement show that the context '$\mathbb{N}:Type$' is legal. To indicate this, we write:
> $$\langle\mathbb{N}:Type\rangle\vdash ok.$$
> Next, we can extend this context with a declaration of a natural number, like 'one'. We get the following judgment:
> $$\langle\mathbb{N}:Type,1:\mathbb{N}\rangle\vdash1:\mathbb{N}.$$
> This context is also legal:
> $$\langle\mathbb{N}:Type,1:\mathbb{N}\rangle\vdash ok.$$
> Next we want to introduce the type of a notion of successor function. Using $\rightarrow$, it follows that:
> $$\langle\mathbb{N}:Type, 1:\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}:Type\rangle\vdash ok.$$

Comment: Without the context $\Gamma$, $1$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are free variables. The task of a context is precisely to bind variables.

Comment: Hi @OlivierRoche, thanks for the answer! Then how can we distinguish between $1:\mathbb{N}$ and $x:\mathbb{N}$? It seems to me that the latter is a variable declaration but the former already provides an instantiation $1$ for the variable $x$ in $x:\mathbb{N}$. Let me know if I mistake it.

Comment: That $\Gamma$ does not look like a context in the standard sense of the word. $1$ and $\sf{suc}(\sf{suc}(1))$ are not variable names. Perhaps you can link to your handouts to give some more context?

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is declared as a *type* (the natural numners). $1 : \mathbb N$ defines the constant $1$ as denoting a number (the number *one*)

Comment: @varkor Hi! I only have a hard copy but I already paste the text in my question. Please take a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: The notion of context here looks like what some texts would call a signature, which is essentially a declaration of axioms. This is suggested by the fact that the elements of the list are being given suggestive names, like $\mathbb N$ and $1$. It's unusual, though, in that $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ ought to be a derived type, from the definition of the $\to$ type constructor. This is the same problem as with the $\sf{suc}(\sf{suc}(1))$ in the original post. Contexts should contain variables, signatures should contain axioms, but neither should contain composite terms.

Comment: It appears that your text is using a nonstandard notion of context, which is why you're finding a mismatch between the usual definition in textbooks (a list of typed variable names) and the definition in your handout. I would suggest treating the definition in the handout as distinct from the other definitions you've found, but be aware that this means you'll need to take extra care when referring to other sources. From the snippets you've posted, it's not completely clear to me what the handout's notion of "context" refers to, in standard terminology.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for the detailed reply. I think the notion of context defined in my handout is standard as it says that ''A context is a listing of everything that has been assumed so far. Formally, it consists of a sequence of variable declarations.'' But then the above example appears, as an illustration for how a context is shaped and extended... That makes me feel rather confused because I can't see any variable but only defined constants... Thanks again!

Comment: That description seems at odds with the examples, yes. It would be worth getting in touch with the person who wrote the handout, if you can. They're the best person to know what they intended!